# How set datagird row background color, by checking a value? c#

Tags: c#

I have a data grid in my c# project. in that data grid there is a column named 'CurrentSituation'. In that column there are two values.. one value is "ORDERED" and the other is "NOTORDERED"..

Here is i want to do.... I want to change data grid row background color to red, if 'CurrentSituation' column value is equal to "ORDERED".

What is the code for that..???

```
private void frmVehicales_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.dtSet.Tables.Clear();
    dtgVehicals.Rows.Clear();
    dtgVehicals.Refresh();

    Form1.con.Open();
    Form1.dtAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AyuboVehicales", Form1.con);
    Form1.dtAdapter.Fill(Form1.dtSet, "AyuboVehicales");
    Form1.con.Close();

    int currentRow = 0;
    int rowCount = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows.Count;

    while (currentRow < rowCount)
    {
        string Vbrand = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        string Vname = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[2].ToString();
        string Vnumber = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[3].ToString();
        string Vtype = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[4].ToString();
        string Vcategory = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[5].ToString();
        string OneDchrg = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[6].ToString();
        string OneWchrg = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[7].ToString();
        string OneMchrg = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[8].ToString();
        string DriverCrg = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[9].ToString();
        string PicPath = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[10].ToString();
        string situation = Form1.dtSet.Tables["AyuboVehicales"].Rows[currentRow].ItemArray[11].ToString();

        dtgVehicals.Rows.Add(Vbrand, Vname, Vnumber, Vtype, Vcategory, OneDchrg, OneWchrg, OneMchrg, DriverCrg, PicPath, situation);
        currentRow++;
    }
    ////CODE WILL PUT HERE
    if(dtgVehicals.Rows.)

}
```

Comment: Use the RowPrePaint event

Answer (score 0):

if (situation == "ORDERED")
   dtgVehicles.BackColor = Color.Red;

You have to use System.Drawing for this to work.

Comment: can you please tell me how i code the situation ..?